# Laravel stevebauman/location returning wrong data

Tags: laravel, location, package, geoip

Using:

- Larvel 4.2
- Location package from https://github.com/stevebauman/location

I am developing an app locally with the details above but when using the package the data I get back isn't correct.

I have tested this in two ways, first with automatic ip detection **eg: Location::get();** and second by manually inputing my ip **eg: Location::get('192.168.1.1');**

Every time I get this same data back:

```
object(Stevebauman\Location\Objects\Location)[141]
  public 'countryName' => string 'United States' (length=13)
  public 'countryCode' => string 'US' (length=2)
  public 'regionCode' => string 'CA' (length=2)
  public 'regionName' => string 'California' (length=10)
  public 'cityName' => string 'Mountain View' (length=13)
  public 'zipCode' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'isoCode' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'postalCode' => string '94043' (length=5)
  public 'latitude' => float 37.4192
  public 'longitude' => float -122.0574
  public 'metroCode' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'areaCode' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'isp' => string 'Google Inc.' (length=11)
  public 'ip' => string '66.102.0.0' (length=10)
  public 'driver' => string 'Stevebauman\Location\Drivers\Telize' (length=35)
  public 'error' => boolean false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Bearing in mind Im from **United Kingdom** not the "United States"

Comment: Hi, I'm the developer for the location package. I'm glad you've figured out your issue! If you encounter any more issues, please create an issue on the git repository: https://github.com/stevebauman/location/issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have figured this out.. There is a **localhost_testing** variable in the packages config file which needs to be set to **false**.

Comment: This was updated to: 'testing' => [

        'enabled' => true,

        'ip' => '66.102.0.0',

    ],